# I am working on optimizing database query for search operation in my application facing performance issue

Tags: .net, sql-server, model-view-controller

We have a table containing around 2 billions record and we want to apply autocomplete search i.e as soon as user types input should show the top five lists. And as per the business requirement, there should be conditional search in the different columns. For example as soon as user types first three characters it should first search in Column1 if it finds data there then returns top 5 data else go to Column2 then search if found then returns top five data and so on.

Also, search result should get filtered as the user keeps on typing words
for examples, search key: "10 Main St Middletown" results should get filtered on the basis of result found for 10 then '10 main' then "10 main st" and so on.

please tell me how to make the performance faster

Comment: Please add in which RDBMs this refers to, a schema, a query, a query plan and ideally some sample data / expected output. As it stands we couldn't provide anything more than 'vague' advice which may or may not fit your situation.

Comment: Its Sql server database